# Making a DIV clickable

Tags: html, css

I was instructed to wrap an anchor tag around a DIV to make the following PHP clickable. My instincts is that this is a bad idea because it's not valid and bad for SEO, so we can dismiss that idea all together - no need to generate back and forth on that advice. So what would the proper way to make everything in the "box-wrap" DIV point to a link?

```
<div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box">
        <header>            
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'categories', '<h3 class="entry-by">' . __('Posted In: ', 'okay'), ', ', '</h3>' ); ?>
        </header>
    </div><!-- box -->
</div><!-- box wrap -->
```

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to achieve by wrapping a div around your anchor tag?

Comment: @Swordfish0321 -  I'm trying to customize this WordPress theme:
http://themes.okaythemes.com/browse/?theme=verb

As of right now the div is not clickable, only the link within the div. I was hoping to make the whole div click to the location of the text that is generated. Wah wah wah ... looks like this out of scope for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As of HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes), you *can* legally wrap it in an `<a>`. In your example, just replace the outer div with an `a` tag.

```
<a class="box-wrap" href="...">
    <div class="box">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Here's a link to the [block/transparent changes made to `<a>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes) in HTML5.

Comment: @Eric This appears to be the way to go, although I think I'm more in a pickle with the PHP. There are multiple links within the DIV that are now defaulting to the DIV anchor instead of the dynamic links that are being generated. Thanks for the help, tho. Def. learned a great deal.

Comment: @Eric  as to why I'm trying to do this, I'm trying to customize this WordPress theme: themes.okaythemes.com/browse/?theme=verb As of right now the div is not clickable, only the link within the div. I was hoping to make the whole div click to the location of the text that is generated. Looks like this out of scope for me.

Comment: @JaggsWaggert: In what way is replacing the outer div with an a not working for you? Can you produce a simple test-case on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your div "clickable" you should use javascript:

```
$("#clickableDivId").click(function() {
    window.location = "your url";
});
```

You can also add css style `cursor: pointer;` to your div looks like anchor.

Comment: @op: Note that using JavaScript instead of a tags is bad for both SEO and the user. Don't do it.